# OnClick focus in Textfield with animation

Tags: jquery, animation, onclick, focus, textfield

I have tried focus **without animation** and its working perfect.
Like this:

```
document.forms['search_form'].elements['search'].focus()
```

**What i want to do?:**

```
I am using Animation (Which is working Perfect). So how can i set Focus into 
the **textfield** with Animation.
```

**Purpose of doing So:**

```
So that i dont have to click into the textfield for typing anything in it.
```

**Here is my CODE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/HBgwx/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#search').offset().top
    }, 500);
    $("#search").focus();
    return false;
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HBgwx/5/)**

Comment: Right Now i am scrolling from Top to bottom.. What to do when Scroll from Bottom to Top ?